# Cant Create Keyboard with NetTelegramBotApi in C#

Tags: c#, keyboard, telegram

i want to create a keyboard in telegram bot with c#, but i cant,
when i add the keyboards show me the error.

nuget pakage is : Install-Package NetTelegramBotApi

this is a my own code.

```
namespace TelegramBotConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        // Keyboards
        public static ReplyKeyboardMarkup MainMenu;
        // Telegram Bot Token.
        private static string BotToken="Bot_Api";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Add The Keuboards
            MainMenu = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup
            {
                Keyboard = new[] { new[] { "Amuzeshha" }, new[] { "Rahnama", "About" } }
            };
        // Running The Bot.
        Task.Run(() => RunBot());
        // Read The Log of Bot.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    // Create Bot.
    public static async Task RunBot()
    {
        var Bot = new TelegramBot(BotToken);
        var Me = await Bot.MakeRequestAsync(new GetMe());
        // Geting The Infromation of Bot.
        Console.WriteLine("Username Is : {0}", Me.Username);
        Console.WriteLine("My ID Is : {0}", Me.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("My Name Is : {0}", Me.FirstName);
        long offset = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            var updates = await Bot.MakeRequestAsync(new GetUpdates() { Offset = offset });
            foreach (var update in updates)
            {
                offset = update.UpdateId + 1;
                var text = update.Message.Text;
                if (text == "/start")
                    {
                        var Req = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "You Should Send Picture") { ReplyMarkup = MainMenu };
                        await Bot.MakeRequestAsync(Req);
                        continue;
                    }
                if(update.Message.Photo == null)
                {
                    var Req = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "Please Send A Picture") { ReplyMarkup = MainMenu };
                    await Bot.MakeRequestAsync(Req);
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    var Req = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "Thanks") { ReplyMarkup = MainMenu};
                    await Bot.MakeRequestAsync(Req);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code does not working.

```
MainMenu = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup
        {
            Keyboard = new[] { new[] { "Amuzeshha" }, new[] { "Rahnama", "About" } }
        };
```

where is the problem?

and this a screen shot of error.
[image]

Comment: The error message is telling you to use the right type.

Answer (score 2):

```
Keyboard = new[] {
    new[] { 
        new KeyboardButton("Amouzeshha"), 
        new KeyboardButton("Help"), 
        new KeyboardButton("About") 
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.